# Can an air conditioner cooling condenser warp when the engine overheats?

Tags: overheating, radiator, accident

My car blew a head gasket. The workshop is now reassembling it. They've told me that because of the heat when the engine overheated, the air conditioner's cooling condenser has warped and needs to be replaced. They have sent me photo's of the faulty one:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm confused about this for a few reasons. I don't understand how they could have not spotted this when they took the engine out. I don't get how this cooler, that sits in front of the main radiator could be warped like this from heat while the main radiator is intact. I very much doubt that this radiator could have reached the kinds of temperatures that could have warped it to this extent.

I suspect that they've swapped my condenser with one that was involved in an accident.

Has anybody ever seen a condenser warp like this before?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've *never* seen a condenser warp like that ... for any other reason besides an accident. Even if the car caught on fire, there's nothing there to get it hot enough to warp it like that. Then, it is contained by bolts and grommets which hold it in so it won't have that happen. Really, I'm not seeing it ... the real problem is, you most likely *cannot* prove it one way or the other unless you saw it to start with. What is the year/make/model/engine of your car? Is it a Ford?

Comment: It's a 2012 Volvo S60 T4 1.6. I'm told that it uses the same engine as the Ford Kuga and Focus.